# AWS Athena table returns a partial result

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a lot of tables in AWS that are agreggated with AWS Athena from an S3 bucket. The bucket has plenty of JSON files. Recently, I noticed that, when I query a table, sometimes I'm getting a half only of a result what I would get normally. For example, a normal result for a certain table/bucket takes about 2.2 gigabytes, but sometimes I'm getting only 1.2 gigabytes. Nothing has changed, and the files do present in s3, although I'm missing the data in the output file what Athea produced.

What might be there reason? Below, please find a sample declaration of a table:

```
  SomeSource:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Table
    Properties:
      CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
      DatabaseName: !Ref AggregatesDB
      TableInput:
        Name: !Sub ${Realm}_foobar
        TableType: EXTERNAL_TABLE
        Parameters: {
          "classification": "json"
        }
        StorageDescriptor:
          OutputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
          InputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
          Location: !Sub s3://${AWS::AccountId}-${xxx}-foo/bar/${Realm}/kek/dunno
          SerdeInfo:
            Parameters:
              ignore.malformed.json: "FALSE"
              mapping: "TRUE"
              dots.in.keys: "FALSE"
              case.insensitive: "TRUE"
            SerializationLibrary: org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe
          Columns:
          - Name: foo
            Type: string
          - Name: bar
            Type: string
          - Name: lol
            Type: string
```

Comment: Is it partitioned data? If so, `msck repair table` might help.